# create UIImageView from delegate in a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, object, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

in my project, I wanted to create dynamically UIImageView directly from the AppDelegate.m to all the 4 Tab Bar Views I have.

Is there any way to do this ? I didn't find anything about that ... The goal is to make the "Reachability" Apple sample work with my Tab Bar Controller (instead of a simple view in the apple sample).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The API for the regular TabBarController does not support defining the individual items with images, as I suppose you want to do. What you will "have to" do is create your own version of TabBarController that supports this. I write "have to" because luckily for you, this is of course quite common to want to do and thus it has been done before.

Recently Jin Budelmann released his version which I've used in a project already and it is absolutely brillaint and easy to use.

Check it out here:
https://github.com/jinthagerman/JBTabBarController (fixed url)

Hope this helps you :)